# In Objective-C Determine if a Property is an int, float, double, NSString, NSDate, NSNumber, etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to determine an object's property (passed by name) type in order to perform deserialization from XML. I have some general pseudo-code (however I am unsure of how to perform these comparisons in Objective-C):

```
id object = [[[Record alloc] init] autorelease];

NSString *element = @"date";
NSString *data = @"2010-10-16";

objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([object class], [element UTF8String]);
const char *attributes = property_getAttributes(property);

char buffer[strlen(attributes) + 1];
strcpy(buffer, attributes);

char *attribute = strtok(buffer, ",");
if (*attribute == 'T') attribute++; else attribute = NULL;

if (attribute == NULL);
else if (strcmp(attribute, "@\"NSDate\"") == 0) [object setValue:[NSDate convertToDate:self.value] forKey:element];
else if (strcmp(attribute, "@\"NSString\"") == 0) [object setValue:[NSString convertToString:self.value] forKey:element];
else if (strcmp(attribute, "@\"NSNumber\"") == 0) [object setValue:[NSNumber convertToNumber:self.value] forKey:element];
```

I have looked through the [class_getProperty](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) and [property_getAttributes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), however I am still not sure how to do the above comparisons.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

@Ahruman's answer is correct, if you're dealing with objects.  Let me suggest some alternatives:

1. `valueForKey:`:  If you use `[myObject valueForKey:@"myPropertyName"]`, it will return an object.  If the property corresponds to some sort of primitive (`int`, `float`, `CGRect`, etc), then it will be boxed for you into an `NSNumber` or `NSValue` (as appropriate).  If it comes back as an `NSNumber`, you can then easily extract a double representation (`doubleValue`) and use that as an `NSTimeInterval` to create an `NSDate`.  I would probably recommend this approach.
2. Special case each type.  `property_getAttributes()` returns a `char*` representing all of the attributes of the property, and you can extract the type by doing this:

   ```
   const char * type = property_getAttributes(class_getProperty([self class], "myPropertyName"));
   NSString * typeString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:type];
   NSArray * attributes = [typeString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
   NSString * typeAttribute = [attributes objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString * propertyType = [typeAttribute substringFromIndex:1];
   const char * rawPropertyType = [propertyType UTF8String];

   if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(float)) == 0) {
     //it's a float
   } else if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(int)) == 0) {
     //it's an int
   } else if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(id)) == 0) {
     //it's some sort of object
   } else ....
   ```

   This is pedantically more correct than Louis's answer, because while *most* types have a single-character encoding, *they don't have to*.  (his suggestion assumes a single-character encoding)
3. Finally, if you're doing this on a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, then I would encourage checking out `NSPropertyDescription`.

From these alternatives, you can probably see that letting the runtime box the value for you is probably simplest.

**edit** extracting the type:

From the code above, you can extract the class name like so:

```
if ([typeAttribute hasPrefix:@"T@"] && [typeAttribute length] > 1) {
  NSString * typeClassName = [typeAttribute substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [typeAttribute length]-4)];  //turns @"NSDate" into NSDate
  Class typeClass = NSClassFromString(typeClassName);
  if (typeClass != nil) {
    [object setValue:[self convertValue:self.value toType:typeClass] forKey:element];
  }
}
```

And then instead of using class method categories to do the conversion (ie, `[NSDate convertToDate:]`), make a method on `self` that does that for you and accepts the desired type as a parameter.  You could (for now) do it like:

```
- (id) convertValue:(id)value toType:(Class)type {
  if (type == [NSDate class]) {
    return [NSDate convertToDate:value];
  } else if (type == [NSString class]) {
    return [NSString convertToString:value];
  } ...
}
```

Part of me is wondering, though: why on earth are you needing to do things this way?  What are you making?

Comment: +1 valueForKey:/setValueForKey:. The autoboxing/unboxing uses NSNumber for basic types and NSValue for compound types (i.e. structs); for more details, see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/DataTypes.html

Comment: Thanks Dave for the detailed response! I am not sure how to utilize the first method (won't valueForKey return nil until I've finished decoding the object, as all the properties will be nil? The second method (the method I have been attempting), works for scalars, but doesn't appear to work for non-scalars. For example, '@encode(NSDate *)' gives "@", but getting the attributes for '@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date' gives "T@"NSDate",&,N,Vdate" (not sure why the attribute section isn't the same, it says it uses @encode). Any ideas? I updated my question with my latest code. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin yes, the 1st option requires an instance of the object.  As for the second, I forgot that property encodes a bit more about the type than `@encode` does.  However, you could use this your advantage.  If the first character is `@`, then see if you can extract a class name from between the `"` marks.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I did one more update to my code with my tentative final version. Just one last question, do you know if a similar compiler directive to '@encode' exists that will result in @encode(NSString *) = '@"NSDate"'? Hard coding these values (as I did above) doesn't seem like the ideal solution. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @DaveDeLong I've edited your answer slightly. When putting the "extracting the type" part of this code into use, I noticed you are looking for a string like `@"NSArray"` when the actual string in `typeAttribute` is like `T@"NSArray"`. I've added the `T` and adjusted the `NSRange` accordingly. Thanks for this example!

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks for this. I'm just concerned about the use of the hard-coded range `(3, [typeAttribute length]-4)`. Is this guaranteed safe? Will the type name *always* be 3 characters in and 4 from the end of the first comma-delimited component of the encoding? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about classes you can use `isKindOfClass:`, but if you want to deal with scalars you are correct that you need to use `property_getAttributes()`, it returns a string that encodes the type information. Below is a basic function that demonstrates what you need to do. For examples of encoding strings, look [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW5).

```
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([object class], &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    char *property_name = property_getName(property);
    char *property_type = property_getAttributes(property);

    switch(property_type[1]) {
      case 'f' : //float
        break;
      case 's' : //short
        break;
      case '@' : //ObjC object
        //Handle different clases in here
        break;
    }
}
```

Obvviously you will need to add all the types and classes you need to handle to this, it uses the normal ObjC @encode [types](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100).

Comment: Note that property attributes aren't just Objective-C type encodings, they also encode information about the property itself (e.g. the names of non-default getters & setters it represents, its atomicity and memory management behavior, etc.).

Comment: True, though in the above example I am keying off of the second char in the string, which is the type info. The rest of info requires more complex parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

`[object isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]`, etc.

Comment: This won't work because I don't have access to the property object (it will be nil before the object is deserialized).