# property type or class using reflection

Tags: objective-c, reflection, deserialization, introspection

I was wondering if it's possible to determine the class or primitive type of an Objects properties. Getting all properties names and values is pretty easy. [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299841/objective-c-introspection-reflection)

So is there any way to get the properties class type while the property hast no value or nil value?

Example Code

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *aDate;
@property                   NSInteger aPrimitive;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize aString;
@synthesize aDate;
@synthesize aPrimitive;

- (void)getTheTypesOfMyProperties {
    unsigned int count;
    objc_property_t* props = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = props[i];

        // Here I can easy get the name or value
        const char * name = property_getName(property);

        // But is there any magic function that can tell me the type?
        // the property can be nil at this time
        Class cls = magicFunction(property);
    }
    free(props);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After searching through [Apples Documentation about objc Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW1) and according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3497822/633945) I finally got it working. I just want to share my results.

```
unsigned int count;
objc_property_t* props = class_copyPropertyList([MyObject class], &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    objc_property_t property = props[i];
    const char * name = property_getName(property);
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char * type = property_getAttributes(property);
    NSString *attr = [NSString stringWithCString:type encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString * typeString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:type];
    NSArray * attributes = [typeString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString * typeAttribute = [attributes objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * propertyType = [typeAttribute substringFromIndex:1];
    const char * rawPropertyType = [propertyType UTF8String];

    if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(float)) == 0) {
        //it's a float
    } else if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(int)) == 0) {
        //it's an int
    } else if (strcmp(rawPropertyType, @encode(id)) == 0) {
        //it's some sort of object
    } else {
        // According to Apples Documentation you can determine the corresponding encoding values
    }

    if ([typeAttribute hasPrefix:@"T@"]) {
        NSString * typeClassName = [typeAttribute substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [typeAttribute length]-4)];  //turns @"NSDate" into NSDate
        Class typeClass = NSClassFromString(typeClassName);
        if (typeClass != nil) {
            // Here is the corresponding class even for nil values
        }
    }

}
free(props);
```

Comment: Isn't your if statement redundant? If typeAttribute has that prefix, doesn't it automatically have a length > 1 since the prefix is 2 characters?

Comment: That's a very nice thing to know, and I'm glad I found your answer! This is absolutely great for parsing bullsh*t into ObjC classes, for example when the API guys decided to send everything as Strings :(:(:(

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wanted to add that according to documentation, different integer types are encoded differently: int -> TI, long -> TL, long long -> TQ. BTW, the "TQ" one isn't in the documentation.

Comment: ¿are we sure that UTF8Encoding is correct for property names?

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure about that. It could also be ACSII encoding. The reference doesn't say it for this function. May be in some "general information about obj-c runtime says it" (can't find it). https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101

Comment: This has a tricky bug with id types -- The encoding for id properties is just "T@", so it will pass the last if check, but [typeAttribute length]-4 will be negative and things will blow up.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the ObjC answer by @arndt-bieberstein I have written a solution in Swift 3 (probably very similar - if not same - in earlier versions of Swift). You can find it on [Github](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftReflection) I am trying to make a pod of it but I am having issues getting `pob lib lint`to work with the Swift 3 code (CLI `xcodebuild` or Xcode 8 related problem probably.) Anyhow, the class method `func getTypesOfProperties(inClass clazz: NSObject.Type) -> Dictionary<String, Any>?` can extract the name and types of any Swift class that inherits from `NSObject`.

The work horse of the project are these methods, but checkout the full code on [Github](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftReflection):

```
  func getTypesOfProperties(in clazz: NSObject.Type) -> Dictionary<String, Any>? {
        var count = UInt32()
        guard let properties = class_copyPropertyList(clazz, &count) else { return nil }
        var types: Dictionary<String, Any> = [:]
        for i in 0..<Int(count) {
            guard let property: objc_property_t = properties[i], let name = getNameOf(property: property) else { continue }
            let type = getTypeOf(property: property)
            types[name] = type
        }
        free(properties)
        return types
    }

   func getTypeOf(property: objc_property_t) -> Any {
        guard let attributesAsNSString: NSString = NSString(utf8String: property_getAttributes(property)) else { return Any.self }
        let attributes = attributesAsNSString as String
        let slices = attributes.components(separatedBy: "\"")
        guard slices.count > 1 else { return getPrimitiveDataType(withAttributes: attributes) }
        let objectClassName = slices[1]
        let objectClass = NSClassFromString(objectClassName) as! NSObject.Type
        return objectClass
    }

   func getPrimitiveDataType(withAttributes attributes: String) -> Any {
        guard let letter = attributes.substring(from: 1, to: 2), let type = primitiveDataTypes[letter] else { return Any.self }
        return type
    }

   func getNameOf(property: objc_property_t) -> String? {
        guard let name: NSString = NSString(utf8String: property_getName(property)) else { return nil }
        return name as String
    }
```

It can extract the `NSObject.Type` of all properties which class type inherits from `NSObject` such as `NSDate` (Swift3: `Date`), `NSString`(Swift3: `String`?) and `NSNumber`, however it is store in the type `Any` (as you can see as the type of the value of the Dictionary returned by the method). This is due to the limitations of `value types` such as Int, Int32, Bool. Since those types do not inherit from NSObject, calling `.self` on e.g. an Int - `Int.self` does not return NSObject.Type, but rather the type `Any`. Thus the method returns `Dictionary<String, Any>?` and not `Dictionary<String, NSObject.Type>?`.

You can use this method like this:

```
class Book: NSObject {
    let title: String
    let author: String?
    let numberOfPages: Int
    let released: Date
    let isPocket: Bool

    init(title: String, author: String?, numberOfPages: Int, released: Date, isPocket: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        self.released = released
        self.isPocket = isPocket
    }
}

guard let types = getTypesOfProperties(inClass: Book.self) else { return }
for (name, type) in types {
    print("'\(name)' has type '\(type)'")
}
// Prints:
// 'title' has type 'NSString'
// 'numberOfPages' has type 'Int'
// 'author' has type 'NSString'
// 'released' has type 'NSDate'
// 'isPocket' has type 'Bool'
```

You can also try to cast the `Any` to `NSObject.Type`, which will succeed for all properties inheriting from `NSObject`, then you can check the type using standard `==` operator:

```
func checkPropertiesOfBook() {
    guard let types = getTypesOfProperties(inClass: Book.self) else { return }
    for (name, type) in types {
        if let objectType = type as? NSObject.Type {
            if objectType == NSDate.self {
                print("Property named '\(name)' has type 'NSDate'")
            } else if objectType == NSString.self {
                print("Property named '\(name)' has type 'NSString'")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you declare this custom `==` operator:

```
func ==(rhs: Any, lhs: Any) -> Bool {
    let rhsType: String = "\(rhs)"
    let lhsType: String = "\(lhs)"
    let same = rhsType == lhsType
    return same
}
```

You can then even check the type of `value types` like this:

```
func checkPropertiesOfBook() {
    guard let types = getTypesOfProperties(inClass: Book.self) else { return }
    for (name, type) in types {
        if type == Int.self {
            print("Property named '\(name)' has type 'Int'")
        } else if type == Bool.self {
            print("Property named '\(name)' has type 'Bool'")
        }
    }
}
```

**LIMITATIONS**
I have not yet been able to give this project support for when the `value types` are optionals. If you have declared a property in you NSObject subclass like this: `var myOptionalInt: Int?` my solution will not work, because the method `class_copyPropertyList` can't find those properties.

**Does anyone have a solution for this?**

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421312/cant-fetch-optional-variables-with-class-copypropertylist-in-swift/48265855#48265855

I can find optionals in Obj-C using class_copyPropertyList.

Only caveat I'm getting is NSKeyedUnarchiver seems to be throwing an exception trying to read back an optional NSNumber blob from CoreData. A regular NSNumber works. Just not an optional.