# How to get all the properties of a ViewController that are subclasses of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, reflection, uiview

I want to use reflection to get all the properties of a `ViewController`, that are subclasses of `UIView`.

I have this method to get all the properties:

```
unsigned count;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

NSMutableArray *rv = [NSMutableArray array];

unsigned i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
    [rv addObject:name];
}

free(properties);
```

But how do I find which type this property is?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861204/property-type-or-class-using-reflection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find type via:

```
 const char * propertyAttrs = property_getAttributes(property);
```

The output will be like the following:

```
(lldb) p propertyAttrs
(const char *) $2 = 0x0065f74d "T@"UICollectionView",W,N,V_collectionView"
```

Where `"T@"UICollectionView"` is property type.

**UPDATE**

I've played with it. This code is not ideal and not tested well, but it works:

```
const char * property_getTypeString( objc_property_t property )
{
    const char * attrs = property_getAttributes( property );
    if ( attrs == NULL )
        return ( NULL );

    static char buffer[256];
    const char * e = strchr( attrs, ',' );
    if ( e == NULL )
        return ( NULL );

    int len = (int)(e - attrs);
    memcpy( buffer, attrs, len );
    buffer[len] = '\0';

    return ( buffer );
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &count);

    NSMutableArray *rv = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];

        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];

        const char * typeString = property_getTypeString(property);

        NSString *type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:typeString];

        NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\""];
        NSArray *splitString = [type componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];

        Class classType = NSClassFromString(splitString[1]);

        BOOL result = [classType isSubclassOfClass:UIView.class];

        [rv addObject:name];
    }

    free(properties);

}
```

The function **property_getTypeString** is borrowed from here: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit

Comment: what does this line mean (const char *) $2 = 0x0065f74d "T@"UICollectionView",W,N,V_collectionView"

Comment: you are missing : "if(result) then add to array" in the line before last, but indeed this does the job, thank you!

Comment: how can i set an attribute to these properties, so that later i can use this attribute without reflection ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check `runtime.h`  `property_getAttributes(property_name)`

as an example:

```
 // will return what type the property is
  const char * propertyAttrs = property_getAttributes(property);
```

Comment: i can get the attributes, but how do i determine that the property i am looking at is a subclass of UIView ?

Comment: in your case the property result will be like (const char *) propertyAttrs = 0x00007985 "T@"UIView",&,N,V_thisPropertySix" as you can see it specify the property is a UIView

Comment: so i just check if this property has the string "UIView" in it ? what if this is a UIButton or a UILabel ? which are subclasses of UIView ?

Comment: yup it will still be able to show if its a UIButton or a UILabel. have a try and see