# Can't fetch optional variables with class_copyPropertyList in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I use following class `Serializable` to convert class Object to Json. See [LINK](https://gist.github.com/turowicz/e7746a9c035356f9483d)

```
 var aClass : AnyClass? = self.dynamicType
    var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
    let propertiesInAClass : UnsafePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertiesCount)
    var propertiesDictionary : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    for var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++ {
        var property = propertiesInAClass[i]
        var propName = NSString(CString: property_getName(property), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var propType = property_getAttributes(property)
        var propValue : AnyObject! = self.valueForKey(propName);
   /* ... */ 
 }
```

It works fine however when class contains optional value, the `class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertiesCount)` doesn't see it.

Consider following basic class:

```
class Person : Serializable{
  var age = 1
  var name = "no name yet"
  var hasMail:Bool?

}
```

Even if I will write:

```
var person = Person()
person.hasMail =  true
```

I get only:

```
age
name
```

To make it work I need write `var hasMail:Bool = false`

---

For Playground (copy/paste)

```
class User : NSObject{
    var age = 1
    var name = "no name yet"
    var hasMail:Bool?

}

var person = User()
person.hasMail =  true

 var aClass : AnyClass? = person.dynamicType
var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
let propertiesInAClass : UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertiesCount)

 println(propertiesInAClass)

for var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++ {
    var property = propertiesInAClass[i]
    var propName = NSString(CString: property_getName(property), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(propName)
}
```

How to get optional name?

Thanks,

Comment: Even it is no answer: It is a bad idea to do "automatic" serialization reading the class' property list. I wrote tons of classes containing computed properties that should not be serialized to nowhere.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad In java world you have plugin `Gson` that converts any class to Json no matter how class is complicated. So advice to stop to try serialize automatically has no sense. Thanks anyways

Comment: The advice is senseless, because there is a plugin in java? Funny joke …

Answer (score 4):

`Foundation` provides a bridge from `Bool` to `NSNumber` (as well as bridges for `Int`, `String`, etc.), but it does not provide a bridge for `Bool?`. That's why it is not visible to Objective-C. If you were to try to annotate `hasMail` with `@objc`, it would give an error, whereas it would work for the other properties.

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation. So it is just plain impossible? :(

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 w/ XC9.2, I'm seeing Swift optionals in Obj-C. Here's the code I use:

In Swift class:

```
    @objc var optionalNumber:NSNumber?
```

In Objective-C code:

```
Class              object         =   MyClass.class;
unsigned int       numProperties  =   0;
objc_property_t*   classProps     =   class_copyPropertyList(object, &numProperties);

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numProperties; index++)
{
      objc_property_t     aProperty   =   classProps[index];
    //...
}
```

at wich point I'm seeing:

> (lldb) po attributes
>
> "T@\"NSNumber\",N,&,VoptionalNumber"

I'm still having issues with CoreData crashing when it tried to map it's model to an optional NSNumber but I'll probably end up mapping NSNumber to a decimal at runtime to get around the issue (if I use a non-optional NSNumber in the swift class everything works fine so it looks like a CoreData bug).

*As a reference, this is part of code that provides automatic Class to CoreData entity model without having to keep an xcdatamodeld in sync with dynamic code.*