# how can i get objc_property_t type

Tags: ios, iphone, runtime

i can get `objc_property_t property` name by `property_getName(property)`

```
unsigned int outCount;

objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([model class], &outCount);

for (int i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {

    objc_property_t property = properties[i];

    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];

}
```

but how can i get the type about `property` like CGFloat or NSString or NSInteger....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `objc_property_t`, you need to call `property_getAttributes()` and then the property type is at the front of a rather cryptic string - to see some code that parses the result of that, see this answer:

[property type or class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861204/property-type-or-class-using-reflection)