# testing object for key instead of keys value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using `valueForKey:` to check `isKindOfClass:`. But some of these do not have a value and thus don't return anything. How do I test the actual key rather than the value of the key? If `object.animal` is an `NSString` with @"Cat" then obviously `[[object valueForKey @"animal"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` checks out as a string. But if `object.animal` hasn't been given a value, I still want to know what kind of property `animal` was meant to be.

Comment: How can it be unclear what I'm asking if someone answered it? Not only answered it, but did so fairly quickly. Although closed because it's answered wouldn't be a bad reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain this information using Objective-C runtime for properties. If you have

```
@property (readonly) NSString *animal;
```

You can use following code:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

// ... 

objc_property_t property = class_getProperty(object.class, "animal");
const char* attr = (property != NULL) ? property_getAttributes(property) : NULL;
```

`attr` is C string, like following: `"T@\"NSString\",R"`. You can extract class name from this string. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/property_getAttributes) regarding `property_getAttributes` result. Note that this solution will only work, if `animal` is declared as property.

Much easier way to handle this situation:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *animal;
+ (Class)animalClass;

@end

@implementation MyObject

+ (Class)animalClass {
    return [NSString class];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Bill3 you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is here [property type or class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861204/property-type-or-class-using-reflection)

Although I must point out using this is highly unadvisable. You might want to re think your approach if your really need to resort to this.

Comment: Why down vote? This is legitimate answer to his question. Even though what he is trying to do is unadvisable, but it is possible

Comment: I didn't downvote. Although I see it all the time in questions and answers.